# Microsoft Excel Countif when cells contain unique strings separated by commas

Tags: excel

I have a project I am working on where I would like to count the amount of times a state's abbreviation shows up in a range of cells.

I have gotten it to work with a certain code, however, it doesn't work if the state shows up more than three times (ex: TX, CA, CA, CA, CA). For California, it'll return 3 instead of the 4 that it should.

Here's my current code

```
=COUNTIF(Table1[State],","&I17)+COUNTIF(Table1[State],Stats!‌​I17&",")+COUNTIF(Tab‌​le1[State],Stats!I17‌​)
```

The first COUNTIF takes into account if it follows a comma, the next if it precedes, and the last if "CA"(I17) is by itself in a cell.

I attached an example image of what I am trying to do here: [Excel State Objective](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wvJJ0.png)

Comment: Can you please post the code you have tried?

Comment: =COUNTIF(Table1[State],"*,"&I17)+COUNTIF(Table1[State],Stats!I17&",*")+COUNTIF(Table1[State],Stats!I17)

Comment: So everyone can read it better, can you edit your original question and place the code in there? Hard to read in the comments.

Comment: I just added it.

Answer (score 0):

If your data is in cell A1:

```
=(LEN(A1)-LEN(SUBSTITUTE(A1," CA","")))/3
```

Note that this will only work if your string only contains state abbreviations: if it has "TX, CA, My cat is a jerk", it will count the "ca" from "cat" as a valid match. It also assumes that there's a space before "CA", but it doesn't rely on commas (which is probably why your current code isn't working).

Comment: One problem with this code is that if a cell contained only one state (CA, CA, CA, CA, CA, CA) it would miss the first since it doesnt follow a space. And it currently only works when the range is one cell, not an entire column.